# simple twisted receiver for orbited comet server

Tags: python, twisted, orbited

I have an unusual request.

I've just moved to a new apartment and I won't have my internet hooked up for over a week. I'm trying to develop my application using my phone for online documentation. Before I moved I found this video (vodpod.com/watch/4071950-building-real-time-network-applications-for-the-web-with-twisted-and-orbited-part-001?u=snaky&c=snaky) from pycon about orbited/twisted basics, unfortunately I forget how it was done and my phone won't play the video.

Could someone watch the first bit of the video for me and post one of the first python examples? The presenter has a simple reactor (I think) which can relay chat messages from telnet and web clients. I just need the basic example, even the one where each event method just has a "pass" in it, then I can continue from there.

Comment: What? I know this is a bad question, but I simply can't find this code from my phone. The network is slow where I am and I spent all last night and this morning stuck on this.

Comment: Why all the off topicity? You should have asked directly for orbited/twisted examples and might have gotten better results

Comment: Because I know this is *exactly* what I need, and having searched my face off for examples already I can't find something as simple. I can't remember whether it worked off http or TCP, what reactor it used, etc. I'm unfamiliar with the area and searching around for answers in low service is a gruelling task

Comment: What is this <strike>crap</strike> stuff?  Hide thee to the library and use one of those pooters.  Or grab your laptop and go to a coffee shop.

Comment: Sadly I had to sell my car for school money, and didn't think the half hour walk to free WiFi was worth it for a quick peek at a video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL to the code examples used in that video:

http://orbited.org/blog/files/tutorial/examples.tgz

Comment: Thank you! This is even better. Luckily I haven't lost the usb cable For my phone...yet

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the video on Android/Symbian/WinMobile using [SkyFire](http://www.skyfire.com/).

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about this. I'll use it when I get stuck and need an explanation